# Blackberry Animated PopUpScreen

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have to implement a zoom in and out animation for a `PopupScreen` class. I have checked `TransitionContext` and `UiEngineInstance` screen transition effects, but the zoomin and out effects are animated from the screen's center position. I am showing this popup while the user clicks a button and need to animate (zoomin and out) from the button position.

How I can accomplish the above animation effect?